# How to check if a given class has a field and it was initialized?

Tags: java, oop

How to check if given class has specific field and if it is initialized (has value at the moment)?

```
abstract class Player extends GameCahracter {

}

public class Monster extends GameCahracter{

    public int level = 1;
}
abstract class GameCharacter{

   public void attack(GameCahracter opponent){

         if (opponent instanceof Monster && ){ // << here I have to know is it instance of Monster and if it has initialized value
           }
}
```

Comment: More detail would really help to answer. Code example perhaps?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
//Load the class 

Class clazz = Class.forName("your.class.ClassName");
Field field = clazz.getField("fieldName")
if(field!=null){
 //field exist now check if its initialized or not, or if its primitive field check against its assumed initialized value
 if(ClassName.fieldName!=null){
    //yes initilized
 }
}
```

Comment: actually [`Class.getField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField%28java.lang.String%29) would throw a `NoSuchFieldException` if the field was not found (it wouldn't return null) and its not a good idea to rely on exceptions for checking

Comment: The answer is invalid, as @AhmadY.Saleh has mentioned. getField() doesn't return the null, but throws the exception.

Comment: Yes, getField or even getDecalredField both we cannot rely on, since they throw exception, not return null value.

Comment: we can catch NoSuchFieldException and tell that the field is missing. I wonder why lots of comments here tell that we cannot rely on the exception?? what for then NoSuchFieldException is given to us??

Answer (score 15):

To see if a class has a property without rely on exception, you can use these methods:

```
private Boolean objectHasProperty(Object obj, String propertyName){
    List<Field> properties = getAllFields(obj);
    for(Field field : properties){
        if(field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(propertyName)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static List<Field> getAllFields(Object obj){
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    getAllFieldsRecursive(fields, obj.getClass());
    return fields;
}

private static List<Field> getAllFieldsRecursive(List<Field> fields, Class<?> type) {
    for (Field field: type.getDeclaredFields()) {
        fields.add(field);
    }

    if (type.getSuperclass() != null) {
        fields = getAllFieldsRecursive(fields, type.getSuperclass());
    }

    return fields;
}
```

And simply call:

```
objectHasProperty(objInstance, "myPropertyName");
```

In fact does not matter the instance of the class to see if the class has the property, but I made that way, just to be little more friendly.
Just to conclude: I made the getAllFields to be recursive, to get all the superclasses methods too (in my case this is important)

After that, if you want to see what is the value of the property in the desired object, you can just call:

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(objInstance, "myPropertyName");
```

Remember: if `objInstance` does not have that property, the call above will throw `NoSuchMethodException` (That is why you need to use the fist code to see if the class has the property)

Comment: Loop in line 17 can be replaced by `Collections.addAll(fields, type.getDeclaredFields());`

Answer (score 7):

You can use reflection, for example like this:

```
Class.forName("Foo").getFields()
```

And then you can check again if particular object has this field initialiazed by using reflection.

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to use reflection for this you can simply do it with if condition.

```
 if (opponent !=null && opponent instanceof Monster && ((Monster) opponent).level==1){ // << here I have to know is it instance of Monster and if it has initialized value
           }
```

You can check the instance is not null if instance not null and its an instance of Monster then in your case its definitely initialized. Instance Variables initialized with default values whenever a new instance created if the opponent instance of a monster then level has value 1.

Comment: is it (Monster) opponent).level=1 or (Monster) opponent).level==1?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. [never use reflection if you don't have to](https://dzone.com/articles/avoid-reflection)

In this solution, if you ever came to change the name of "level" you're IDE will probably update this line of code too. Or at least you'll have a compilation error instead of a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @Renato Lochetti i want to add a variant with only a single function, not using 3:

```java
private boolean hasField(final Class<?> clazz, final String fieldName) {
    // gather all fields of this class
    final List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    Class<?> current = clazz;
    do {
        Collections.addAll(fields, current.getDeclaredFields());
    } while ((current = clazz.getSuperclass()) != null);

    // check if field exists
    return fields.stream().map(Field::getName).anyMatch(f -> f.equals(fieldName));
}
```